# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on browsing to one website

Tags: network, wifi, safari, google-chrome, facebook

I have a 2010 MBP. Just in the last day or so, whenever I try to browse to Facebook (www.facebook.com), I get a **ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED** error.

This is what is displayed in Chrome, however I cannot connect in Safari, Firefox, nor `curl -o fb.txt http://www.facebook.com` from the command line.

As far as I can tell no other websites are affected. In fact, developers.facebook.com and graph.facebook.com work just fine.

Things I've tried:

- What Chrome tells me to do.
- Deleting the browser cache.
- Restarting the computer.
- Shutting down the computer, and rebooting.
- Clearing the DNS cache.
- Using a different Wifi network.
- Using a wired network (and turning off Wifi).

Running Wireshark shows that the Facebook server (173.252.110.27) is returning a "Destination unreachable" ICMP packet whenever I browse.

No other computers or mobile devices on my network are affected, just the MBP.

I'm at a loss as to what to try next!  Any suggestions appreciated.

I'm wondering if my network stack is somehow corrupted?

[image]

Comment: Not if only on your MBP. Can only add that I had to do three (3) internet installs (from Recovery Disk) to cure janky trackpad. Seems like all bets are off as to ordinary fixes, never mind customization, in Yosemite, and it can't be a coincidence that Sir Interface is in charge. In the long run, those reinstalls are easiest. I do fear El Capitan or Bridal Falls or whatever it's called...

Comment: Is this on your home network? Or, are you on a school/work network, where facebook.com could be blocked by a proxy?

Comment: Fascinating. Have you don't the typical isolation steps? Make new user on OS X and retest with same stack/app versions? Also, if it's networking, other browsers should fail equivalently, no?

Comment: Are you sure this is the issue of your MBP instead of your network constraints? In all likelihood this is because of the network itself having some restrictions on facebook.com